# How to find rms value of every row from a csv file using python spider IDE?

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler, rms

I have written this code for reading the csv file

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd

ratings_data = pd.read_csv("matrix1.csv")  
ratings_data.head()
```

Now I want the rms value of each row. Is there any way?
rms means root mean square.

Comment: is `rms` a column?

Comment: `print(ratings_data['rms']`

Comment: no, rms means root mean square

Comment: In the title section there are different movie name. Different users have given ratings  1-5 for each movie.

Comment: adding square of each row value, dividing it by the total columns and taking the square root afterwards would do it, no?

Comment: Yes, thats it. But how can i do it in python with Spider IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone or I come up with a built-in/one liner:

```
import math
import pandas as pd

ratings_data = pd.read_csv("matrix1.csv")
for index, row in ratings_data.iterrows():
    print(
        math.sqrt(
            ((ratings_data['col_a'] ** 2) + (ratings_data['col_b'] ** 2) +
          (ratings_data['col_c'] ** 2))/3
        )
    )
```